# How can i create a rule that prevent users to add a date that is greater than now

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to add a rule in my real-time database that would prevent users to insert a date that is bigger than now. The dates that I currently have in my database have been converted to string.

here is an example of date in my database:

> "Sun Apr 21 2019 14:14:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)"

You will find below an example of my current rules.

Any clue as to how can I make a validation from here?
Thank you

```
 {
    /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
    "rules": {
      "users":{
        "$uid":{
          ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
          ".write": "auth.uid == $uid",
          "exercices":{
          "developpeIncline":{
                "$developpeInclineId":{
                    "date":{
                     ".validate":"newData.val() <= now"  // blocks everything at the moment
                  },
                 "reps":{
                   ".validate":"newData.val().length < 3"
                 }
              }
          }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `now` variable in Firebase's security rules is [documented](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#now) as:

> Contains the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch according to the Firebase Realtime Database servers.

Since you store your date as a string, your rules are now comparing different types:

```
"Sun Apr 21 2019 14:14:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)" <= 1555855344955
```

That comparison is never going to be true, since comparing strings and numbers never gives a useful result.

You'll need to write code to get the values to be of the same type to allow the comparison. And since dates as strings are not easily comparable, this means you'll need to convert the string back to a date or to a numeric timestamp.

I don't think this is possible in Firebase's security rules. But even if it was possible, I highly recommend picking a better approach. Store your date as a timestamp:

```
developpeInclineRef.child("timestamp").set(date.getTime());
```

or

```
developpeInclineRef.child("timestamp").set(Date.now());
```

With that the comparison becomes trivial:

```
"timestamp": {
  ".validate":"newData.val() <= now"
},
```

If you want to store the date in a display format too, consider storing it in two formats: as a timestamp, and as a string.

Comment: I decided to convert my date into timestamp, worked like a charm. Thank you.